# sin(A+B) if cos(A) = 3/5 and sin(B) = -4/5 and A is in QI and B is in QIII

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question on an online exercise that doesn't provide an answer or an explanation. I believe I know how to do it, but the answer I get every time is marked wrong when I submit it. I need a 2nd set of eyeballs.

Find sin(A+B) if cos(A) = 3/5 and sin(B) = -4/5 and A is in QI and B is in QIII.

using identities:

sin(A+B) = sin(A)cos(B) + cos(A)sin(B)

plugging in what we know we start with:

sin(A)cos(B) + (3/5)*(-4/5) = sin(A)cos(B) - 12/5

Both of these are 3,4,5 right triangles. 3 and 4 are positive for angle A (QI) and 3 and 4 are negative for angle B (QIII).

sin(A) = 4/5

cos(B) = -3/5

again plugging in we have:

(4/5) * (-3/5) - 12/5

-12/5 - 12/5 = -24/5

That's not the answer, so where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: $(4/5)*(-3/5)=-12/25$, not $-12/5$

Comment: $\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{-4}{5} = \frac{-12}{25}$, not $\frac{-12}{5}$, ditto for the other equation.

Comment: OMG I feel like an idiot thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

Putting the values in

$$\sin(A+B)=(4/5)(-3/5)+(3/5)(-4/5)$$

$$\sin(A+B)= -24/25$$

Comment: OMG I feel like an idiot. thank you.